# Grabbing input from dynamically created textboxes to another form

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, textbox

So, we have a way to dynamically create an array of x by y of texboxes to input values into it to later on do some matrix calculation, like determine the rank of the matrix.

To generate the array we use this:

```
protected void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            for (int row = 0; row < LinhaText; row++)
            {
                List<TextBox> newLin = new List<TextBox>();
                textboxes.Add(newLin);
                for (int col = 0; col < ColunText; col++)
                {
                    TextBox newbox = new TextBox();
                    newbox.Width = textboxWidth;
                    newbox.Height = textboxHeight;
                    newbox.Top = (row * (textboxHeight + spacing)) + spacing + vOffset;
                    newbox.Left = (col * (textboxWidth + spacing)) + spacing + hOffset;
                    newLin.Add(newbox);
                    this.Controls.Add(newbox);

                }
            }
        }
```

This stands on the second form, as in the first one we input the dimensions of the array. When we input the values on the textboxes they should get sent to the third form to get used by the other calculations.
We are wondering how we grab the values and send them to the other form to later on display the results.
Any further information you need, just ask!

Comment: You need to show more code.  Where is `textboxes` declared?  Where is your instance of your second form declared?  Show *all relevant code*.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that these are not modal windows and that the user can switch between them at any point? If that is the case then I would suggest using a design pattern like MVC or MVVM, separating your data, view, and control logic. By keeping the data layer distinct from the view, you can have all of your windows (views) share the same underlying data. Of course, you'll want to use events to notify the various windows of when the data is changed (see the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface).

Comment: That's not what the OP is asking, and it's probably a little more advanced than is necessary based on the clues from the question.

Comment: The question is asking about migrating data between multiple forms - winforms more specifically. I could be interpreting him wrong, but after going back and re-reading I'm still under the same impression.

Comment: I want to send the data from the created text boxes on form 2 to the form 3, as a thing I can call to like a variable, so I can use it in the Gaussian elimination method later on.

Comment: @JoãoFerreira - can you confirm that the user can simultaneously switch between these forms (vs a modal type dialog that must be closed before you can return to the original form)? If so, I maintain that the above answer is the best approach - though it is advanced.

Comment: Oh, it is also important to know if these forms are all launched under the same process or if they are running under distinct processes. If they are under distinct processes then you'll need to use inter process communication: like Microsoft Message Queues.

Comment: The user goes from form to form, starting from the first one where the dimensions of the array are inputed and with a click of a button it goes to the second form where it grabs those 2 global variables to build the array. In the second one, the numbers should be inputed to calculate something in the third form.

Answer (score 1):

I would not pass around textboxes, instead store the numbers in a 2-dimensional array (matrix). Also I would use binding to automatically bind the matrix values to the textboxes. To make binding work, you need a helper class containing your values, because binding needs to bind to a property.

```
private class Data // Can be a nested private class in Form2.
{
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() => Value.ToString(); // Not strictly necessary, but
                                                           // makes debugging easier.
}
```

We create a `_matrix` field as well as a property converting this `Data[,]` matrix to a `double[,]` matrix and returning it (in `Form2`):

```
private Data[,] _matrix;

public double[,] Matrix
{
    get {
        var m = new double[LinhaText, ColunText];
        for (int row = 0; row < LinhaText; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < ColunText; col++) {
                m[row, col] = _matrix[row, col].Value;
            }
        }
        return m;
    }
}
```

Now create the textboxes and bind them to a `Data` object (In `Form2_Load` or in the form constructor after `InitializeComponent`):

```
_matrix = new Data[LinhaText, ColunText];
for (int row = 0; row < LinhaText; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < ColunText; col++) {
        var newbox = new TextBox {
            Width = textboxWidth,
            Height = textboxHeight,
            Top = (row * (textboxHeight + spacing)) + spacing + vOffset,
            Left = (col * (textboxWidth + spacing)) + spacing + hOffset
        };

        // Create Data object, add it to the matrix and bind it to the TextBox.
        var data = new Data();
        _matrix[row, col] = data;
        newbox.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", data, "Value", true));

        Controls.Add(newbox);
    }
}
```

Note that binding works two way. If you initialize the matrix with numbers, they will be displayed in the textboxes when opening the form. Numbers entered in textboxes will be stored in the matrix.

---

Now, on the other form, you need a reference to this form. Then you can get the matrix with

```
double[,] matrix = frmMartixInput.Matrix;
```

If you have difficulties passing around form references, then use a static property in a static class for the matrix, that can be referenced by all the forms.

```
public static class Globals
{
    public static double[,] Matrix { get; set; }
}
```

You can also pass data to a form through constructor parameters (either a reference to another form or the matrix itself).

Comment: Where should I put each piece of the code, excepting the third part?

Comment: In the form with the textboxes (`Form2`).

Comment: When placing the double[,] matrix = frmIntroMatriz.Matrix; it gives an error saying: an object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'frmIntroMatriz.Matrix'
What did I do wrong?

Comment: Because `frmIntroMatriz` is a type (a class). You must reference the form object. E.g. `var frm = new frmIntroMatriz(); frm.ShowDialog(); double[,] matrix = frm.Matrix;`.